# Keyboard Backlight not working

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, backlight, toshiba-satellite

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Satellite P775-S7100. The keyboard backlight was working initially, but after reinstalling the same version of Ubuntu it stopped working, and as far as I can tell, it doesn't interact with Ubuntu at all. Is there any way to fix this short of reinstalling Ubuntu again?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I mean, if you installed the exact same version, it should be worked. Is your system up to date? Maybe, on old installation, you used any extra configuration about backlight ?

Comment: The first time I installed Ubuntu it worked fine by default, so I expected it to after I reinstalled too. It's possible something in the hardware broke around when I reinstalled.